# Why is cout<< 1char + 2char << endl; not giving me the full concatenation of two strings?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
int i = 4;
double d = 4.0;
string s = "HackerRank ";


// Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
int a;
double b;
char c;
// Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
cin>> a;
cin>> b;
cin>> c;
// Note: If you have trouble reading the entire string, please go back and review the Tutorial closely.

// Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
cout <<a + i<< endl;
// Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
printf("%.1lf\n", b + d);
// Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
// The 's' variable above should be printed first.
cout<< s + c << endl;
return 0;}
```

In HackerRank the inputs are already done for you."c" = "is the best place to learn and practice coding!".The program prints "HackerRank i"...and then stops.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: "// Note: If you have trouble reading the entire string, please go back and review the Tutorial closely." I suggest you go back and review that Tutorial closely.

Comment: What is `c`? It is a `char`. What would you _expect_ to happen when adding it to a `string`?

Comment: The best place to learn C++ coding is from a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @TimRandall C is a programming language designed by Dennis Ritchie back in 1972. Oh. Not that C. Hate it when people use one letter variables.

Comment: Don't cross the streams.  Use either `std::cout` or `printf`, not both.  See `set_precision` and `setw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is following:

```
// Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
int a;
double b;
char c;
```

But the last one, is not a string it is a single char. That is why the cin>> c; is reads the first char and cout<< s + c << endl; printd the string plus one char.

you have to change the c to string instead of char